# Cómo hacer menú más grande para ajustarlo a las especificaciones

Tags: css, bootstrap

Miren tengo un menu :

```css
.clase1{
      cursor: pointer;
height: 870px;
width: 500px;
background-color: #e92797;
top: -30px;
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--<html oncontextmenu="return false"> -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />        <title>
        Seadog Creative Labs:
        Pages        </title>
   <meta name="robots" content="noindex"/><meta name="googlebot" content="noindex"/><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Desarrollo/css/myStyle.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css"/>    </head>
<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">
            
            <br>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                </a>
                
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse in" style="height: auto;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu clase1" style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <li><a class="linkMenuHome lang" key="linkHome">Laboratorio estratégico</a></li>
                            <li><a class="linkMenuNeeds lang" key="linkNeeds">Descubrir necesidades</a></li>
                            <li><a class="linkMenuStrategies lang" key="linkStrategies">Definir estrategias</a></li>
                            <li><a class="linkMenuTools lang" key="linkTools">Herramientas</a></li>
                            <li><a class="linkMenuExecution lang" key="linkExecution">Ejecución</a></li>
                            <li><a class="linkMenuResults lang" key="linkResults">Resultados</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="linkMenuExplore lang" key="linkExplore">Explora resultados</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="linkMenuTeam lang" key="linkTeam">Equipo Seadog</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="linkMenuContact lang" key="linkContact">Contáctenos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <br>
        </div>

        <div id="content">


                          
   



   
   


   
    





                            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>                                <script type="text/javascript" src="/Desarrollo/js/myScript.js"></script>                                
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>                


        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <div class="form-inline  row">

                <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <br/>
                                            <ul id="menu" class="navlist social">
                        <li class="contenedor">
                            Social network:
                        </li>
                        <li onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/seadoglabs', '_blank');" class="contenedor">
                            <img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://facebook.com" title="Facebook" class="imagen"/>
                        </li>
                        <li onclick="window.open('https://www.instagram.com/seadoglabs', '_blank');" class="contenedor">
                            <img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://instagram.com" title="Instagram" class="imagen"/>
                        </li>
                        <li onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/company/seadog-creative-labs', '_blank');" class="contenedor">
                            <img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://linkedin.com" title="Linkedin" class="imagen"/>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

y se supone que debe quedar así:

[image: menu]

Y por ahora se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya con el nueve css se ve así, t se supone que debería cubrir desde lo alto de la pagina, hasta abajo y desde la mitad de la pagina hasta la parte derecha de la pagina. ademas los textos deberían distribuirse a lo largo del menu, miren que se quedan centrados arriba.
[image: Ult imagenb]

Comment: No puse css ya que todo el estilo esta en las librerías de bootstrap.

Comment: Si no pones el html junto con el css no podemos ver como llevas la página, si lo adjuntaras podriamos ayudarte

Comment: Listo, ya pongo todo mi css

Comment: Por favor añade más información: ¿qué versión de bootstrap estás usando? ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento y con qué problemas te estás encontrando? Los estilos CSS que has compartido no tienen nada que ver con el código HTML y la redacción de la pregunta es muy pobre y no muestra ningún esfuerzo ni intento real de resolver el problema. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones sobre cómo mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Acabe de agregar un css que intente, y solo hace lo de mi ultima imagen.